# Get information schema from sqlite db

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, information-schema

I want to get a list of all tables and their columns from the current database, like:

```
 table1
  - column1
  - column2
  - column3
 table2
  - column1
  - column2
```

I tried:

`SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=? ORDER BY name;`

(`?` is `'table'`)

but I get only the table list, without the columns :(

If I remove the WHERE clause I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range
```

If I replace `table` with `column` I get nothing...

Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query:

```
pragma table_info(table1);
```

You'll get the following columns:

```
cid // Column Id
name // Column Name
type // Column Type
notnull // If the column is not null
dflt_value // Column default Value
pk // If the column is a primary key
```

Comment: Are you using PDO SQLite in PHP ?

Comment: yes. but it works now, the problems was that my query wrapper function wasn't passing correct parameters :)

Comment: thanks! but that would mean I would have to make like 20 queries for each table :(

Comment: You can get the table names from the first query you were using and then loop through them with the other query to get the columns of each.